# how to make my ios app sdk backward compatible

Tags: ios, ios4, sdk

I've got an app in IOS 4.3 and I'd like to make it up to 4.0 backward compatible.
how may I do that ?

Comment: Make sure it CAN be backward compatible.  If you're using ARC, the app will work at 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-click on your project in Groups & Files, then go to Build->Deployment->iOS Deployment Target and select the target iOS version that you want to build for.

Good Luck.